# Why is de Broglie applied in case of photons

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atomic-structure

**Q:** *Consider a helium (He) atom that absorbs a photon of wavelength 330 nm. The change in the velocity (in cm s¯¹) of He atom after the photon absorption is (Assume: Momentum is conserved when photon is absorbed)
Use: Planck constant = 6.6 * 10 ^ - 34 , Avogadro number = 6x1023 mol-1, Molar mass of He = 4 g mol¯¹)*

My approach:

Calculate Energy of the photon by
 `E = hc/wavelength`

And then equating it with the change in kinetic energy, however the difference is answer is by a factor of 2^1/2

In the solution, they have done it simply by substituting in de Broglie equation. I mean how can we just substitute the mass of helium and the wavelength of photon in the same eqn? And how is my approach wrong?

Comment: Focus on momentum, not energy. For m>0 and v << c, p =m.v. For m=0, p=E/c = hc/(wavelength . c) = h/wavelength

Comment: I understand, but why is the energy approach wrong? Am I missing something about energy conservation, is energy also converted into some other form?

Comment: Why do you think the whole photon energy is transformed to the atom kinetic energy?

Comment: I mean if not K.E. then it will be transformed into which form?

Comment: It could be an electron excitation.

Comment: You might also be interested to look up  details of the Mossbauer Effect.

Answer (score 0):

Einstein's special theory of relativity is the basis of the expression of de Broglie.
the actual expression was

$ E^2=(pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2 $

In case of photons the rest mass was zero. however this is not the case with helium atom. So, you cannot equate change in kinetic energy of a non zero rest mass object with the energy expression of photon mentioned above.

Comment: I don't understand how special relativity is the basis of de Broglie's expression. I think de Broglie was inspired by the photoelectric effect, so he extended the expression $h\nu$ which Einstein applied only to photons to all bodies composed of matter. Am I incorrect?

Comment: yes. He argued nature is symmetric and matter also shows wave nature.